# Doctrine extend Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, single-table-inheritance

I'm using Symfony with Doctrine.

To resolve my problem I want to:

- or When I'm extending Entity class I want the doctrine to ignore parent's class @entity annotation (to see it as @MappedSuperclass)
- or (this one is more preferable) When I'm extending Entity class add to child class something like @MappedChildclass just to know that this class is an Entity, but actual implementation and mappings in the parent class

---

### Lets see concrete problem:

I have 3 bundles:

- AppBridgeBundle
- UserBundle
- ProfileBundle

UserBundle and UserProfile must be decoupled. AppBridgeBundle is a bridge between 2 bundles, it will couple both.

UserBundle has **UserEntity**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
**/
class UserEntity {

     /**
     * @var \Acme\UserBundle\Interfaces\ProfileData
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Interfaces\ProfileData",
                      cascade={"persist"})
     * )
     */
    private $profileData;

     // ...
}
```

UserBundle has its own interface *ProfileData* (decoupled, we only need to inject implementation of this interface).

ProfileBundle has **ProfileEntity**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
**/
class ProfileEntity implements Acme\ProfileEntity\Interfaces\Profile {

     // properties ...

}
```

ProfileBundle has its own interface *Profile* (decoupled).

Basically ProfileData and Profile interfaces are the same.

Now AppBridgeBundle introduces *Adapter* of Profile and ProfileData interfaces to adapt UserBundle with ProfileBundle.

```
class ProfileAdapter  extends \Acme\ProfileBundle\Entity\ProfileEntity
                      implements   \Acme\UserBundle\Interfaces\ProfileData,
                                   \Acme\ProfileBundle\Interfaces\Profile {

}
```

Next, we inject our interface implementation in the `config.yml` app configuration:

```
orm:
     resolve_target_entities:
          Acme\UserBundle\Interfaces\ProfileData: Acme\AppBridgeBundle\Entity\ProfileAdapter
```

Now, the problem is that when I update doctrine schema it throws me an error that `Acme\AppBridgeBundle\Entity\ProfileAdapter` is not *Entity*.

- If I mark ProfileAdapter with `@Entity` then it will create 2 separate tables - I don't need it
- If I mark ProfileAdapter with `@Entity` with the same name as ProfileEntity - `@Table('profileentity')` then it throws me an error that `table profile already exists`
- If I mark ProfileEntity with `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` and `remove @Entity` annotation from it - I'll loose default implementation of the ProfileEntity class (so it cant work without bridge anymore).
- if I mark ProfileEntity with `@InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")` it will add to the tables unnecessary discriminator field to my table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to use the dispatched doctrine "loadClassMetadata" event.
You can track this event in a subscriber which is aware of ProfileEntity inheritance, and inject the "@Entity" or the "@MappedSuperclass" annotation.

You can see an implementation here : https://github.com/victoire/CmsBundle/blob/master/EventSubscriber/LoadMetadataSubscriber.php
In this example, I dynamically inject enabled widgets to the discriminatorMap of my Widget entity.
I let you adapt this code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what I did using your example:

- move `\Acme\ProfileBundle\Entity\ProfileEntity` to `\Acme\ProfileBundle\Model\ProfileEntity`
- redeclare `ProfileEntity` class to `abstract` but leave all the ORM instructions intact
- redeclare `ProfileAdapter` to extend new `ProfileEntity` model
- mark `ProfileAdapter` as `@ORM\Entity` only, all remaining `@ORM*` instructions leave in the model class

Pros:

- no additional tables
- no additional fields
- can work without the bridge

Cons:

- it is necessary to create entity extending abstract model for each new Bundle installation

Comment: If you create complete bundles (but available for extension) you have to create "default entities" anyway, and they will be installed anyway.. also it can be double work (create abstract in the Model and real in the Entity). I think its possible to write addon to introduce "excludable entities configuration", so entities that should be excluded from the installation, but can be used for the extending could be set from the app configuration